# On Ubuntu 18.04, how is `/var/log/journal` created?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, systemd-journald

On my Ubuntu 18.04, I see `/var/log/journal` is created but **I can't figure out what created it in the first place.** **Could somebody help me?** I'll provide more details below.

This is **not** an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'm asking this question for pure curiosity in order to understand `systemd` or Ubuntu better.

### What I have learned

By reading [systemd-journald.service(8)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html) and [journald.conf(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/journald.conf.5.html), I learned that:

- If `Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, `/var/log/journal` is created automatically.
- If `Storage=auto` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, `/var/log/journal` is not created automatically if it doesn't exist. But if the system admin creates `/var/log/journal`, `systemd-journald` will write logs into it. Otherwise, it falls back to using `/run/log/journal`.

On my Ubuntu 18.04, my `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` uses all the default values:

```
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.                                                                  
# You can change settings by editing this file.                                                                         
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.                                                                
#                                                                                                                       
# See journald.conf(5) for details.                                                                                     
                                                                                                                        
[Journal]                                                                                                               
#Storage=auto                                                                                                           
#Compress=yes                                                                                                           
#Seal=yes                                                                                                               
#SplitMode=uid                                                                                                          
#SyncIntervalSec=5m                                                                                                     
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s                                                                                               
#RateLimitBurst=1000                                                                                                    
#SystemMaxUse=                                                                                                          
#SystemKeepFree=                                                                                                        
#SystemMaxFileSize=                                                                                                     
#SystemMaxFiles=100                                                                                                     
#RuntimeMaxUse=                                                                                                         
#RuntimeKeepFree=                                                                                                       
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=                                                                                                    
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100                                                                                                    
#MaxRetentionSec=                                                                                                       
#MaxFileSec=1month                                                                                                      
#ForwardToSyslog=yes                                                                                                    
#ForwardToKMsg=no                                                                                                       
#ForwardToConsole=no                                                                                                    
#ForwardToWall=yes                                                                                                      
#TTYPath=/dev/console                                                                                                   
#MaxLevelStore=debug                                                                                                    
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug                                                                                                   
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice                                                                                                    
#MaxLevelConsole=info                                                                                                   
#MaxLevelWall=emerg                                                                                                     
#LineMax=48K
```

In other words, I'm using `Storage=auto` on my system.

I also learned from [systemd-tmpfiles(8)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service.8.html) and [tmpfiles.d(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) that `systemd-tmpfiles` creates, deletes, and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories, based on the configuration file format and location specified in tmpfiles.d(5).

So I examined the `tmpfiles.d(5)` folders and I only found configuration files under `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` that modify the attributes of `/var/log/journal`, as shown in the following `grep` output:

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d$ grep journal *.conf
journal-nocow.conf:# Set the NOCOW attribute for directories of journal files. This flag
journal-nocow.conf:# WARNING: Enabling the NOCOW attribute improves journal performance
journal-nocow.conf:# enabling the NOCOW attribute for journal files is safe, because
journal-nocow.conf:h /var/log/journal - - - - +C
journal-nocow.conf:h /var/log/journal/%m - - - - +C
journal-nocow.conf:h /var/log/journal/remote - - - - +C
systemd.conf:z /run/log/journal 2755 root systemd-journal - -
systemd.conf:Z /run/log/journal/%m ~2750 root systemd-journal - -
systemd.conf:a+ /run/log/journal/%m - - - - d:group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /run/log/journal/%m - - - - group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /run/log/journal/%m/*.journal* - - - - group:adm:r--
systemd.conf:z /var/log/journal 2755 root systemd-journal - -
systemd.conf:z /var/log/journal/%m 2755 root systemd-journal - -
systemd.conf:z /var/log/journal/%m/system.journal 0640 root systemd-journal - -
systemd.conf:a+ /var/log/journal    - - - - d:group::r-x,d:group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /var/log/journal    - - - - group::r-x,group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /var/log/journal/%m - - - - d:group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /var/log/journal/%m - - - - group:adm:r-x
systemd.conf:a+ /var/log/journal/%m/system.journal - - - - group:adm:r--
```

**But by reading the meanings of `h`, `z`, `Z`, and `a+`, none of them seem to create the folder `/var/log/journal`. All of them seem to only modify the attributes of `/var/log/journal`.**

I did a test in which I deleted the folder `/var/log/journal` and rebooted my computer. Then I saw `/var/log/journal` was not re-created (which was expected because of `Storage=auto` on my machine). Instead, `/run/log/journal` was created (as expected).

**What created `/var/log/journal`?**

Comment: I do not recommend the following unless you do not care if you have to reinstall. With a running machine and a few programs open power off with the power switch. On restart there should be a message a journal is being created.

Comment: @David why does this happen? I would love to know and also that would make a great answer to this question.

Comment: @Esther Why does what happen? If you mean what I suggested to the OP, have you tested it?

Comment: I mean why does a system create /var/log/journal only when it was force-shutdown, even if it usually uses /run/log/journal ?

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment, David. I'm more interested in "what" creates the folder than "how" to create the folder. If it is created by some executable application or script, what is this application or script and where is it located on the computer? If it is created by some configuration, where is this configuration file?

Comment: That is beyond me or any one on this site I imagine. That is a question for the large team that created Ubuntu.

Comment: @Esther and @David: You can take a look at the accepted answer, especially the part about the `postinst` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will focus on why a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 contains a `/var/log/journal` directory.  Other systems may vary.

**Q. Why does a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 contain `/var/log/journal`?**

**A**. The root filesystem image used by the installer contains a `/var/log/journal` file.  The installer essentially copies an embedded image to the target system during installation.  Files and directories contained in the image will be copied to the target system.

The image used by the installer is similar to the ones available in [cloud-images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/).  These commands show that the image contains the `/var/log/journal` directory.  This results in the installed system also containing the directory.

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# wget --quiet https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz
root@ubuntu-server:~# tar tvf jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz | grep var/log/journal
drwxr-sr-x root/systemd-timesync    0 2022-10-19 01:04 var/log/journal/
```

**Q. Why does the image contain `/var/log/journal`?**

**A**. The image contains the package `systemd`.  When the `systemd` package is installed [it will create](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/ubuntu/+source/systemd/tree/debian/systemd.postinst?h=ubuntu-jammy#n69) the `/var/log/journal` directory in its `postinst` script.

From the source

```
# Enable persistent journal, in auto-mode, by default on new installs installs and upgrades
if dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt "235-3ubuntu3~"; then
    mkdir -p /var/log/journal
    # create tmpfiles only when running systemd, otherwise %b substitution fails
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
        systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
    fi
fi
```

**Q. Why does the `systemd` package create `/var/log/journal`?**

**A**. Somebody filed [a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717388) requesting it.

> Please create /var/log/journal, to enable persistent journal logging

Comment: I confirmed that on Ubuntu 18.04, `/var/log/journal` is also created by the `postinst` script of the package `systemd`. I didn't test Ubuntu 20.04 but I believe it's the same behavior.